# Add object to inlineImages sendEmail parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following to loop through all the charts on the sheet name 'Charts' and attach them as inline images.

In the htmlBody, I reference each chart where needed as the string ChartXString.

```
  var Chart1Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Charts');
  var charts1 = Chart1Sheet.getCharts();
  var chartBlobs1=new Array(charts1.length); 
  var emailImages1={};
  for(var i=0;i<charts1.length;i++){
    var builder = charts1[i].modify();
    builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
    var newchart = builder.build();
    chartBlobs1[i]= newchart.getAs('image/png');
    chart1String = "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+0+"'></p>";
    chart2String = "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+1+"'></p>";
    chart3String = "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+2+"'></p>";
    chart4String = "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+3+"'></p>";
    emailImages1["chart"+i]= chartBlobs1[i];
  }


  myHTML = myHTML + myHTML2 + myHTML3 + myHTML4 + myHTML5 + chart1String + chart2String + chart3String + chart4String + myHTML6;
  recipient = 'email@address';
  subject = 'My subject text';
  body = 0;


  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: myHTML, inlineImages:emailImages1});
```

This is working perfectly, however I would like to add an image like [the example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage).

```
  var youtubeLogoUrl =
        "https://developers.google.com/youtube/images/YouTube_logo_standard_white.png";
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                          .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                          .getBlob()
                          .setName("youtubeLogoBlob");
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "Logos",
    htmlBody: "inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>",
    inlineImages:
      {
        youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob
      }
  });
```

I think the problem is not understanding how to add the object. This is what I have tried so far:

```
  var youtubeLogoUrl =
        "https://developers.google.com/youtube/images/YouTube_logo_standard_white.png";
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                          .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                          .getBlob()
                          .setName("youtubeLogoBlob");
LogoStr = "<img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>";

  var Chart1Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Charts');
      ................
    chart4String = "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+3+"'></p>";
    emailImages1["chart"+i]= chartBlobs1[i] + youtubeLogoBlob;
  }


  myHTML = LogoStr + myHTML + myHTML2 + myHTML3 + myHTML4 + myHTML5 + chart1String + chart2String + chart3String + chart4String + myHTML6;
  recipient = 'email@address';
  subject = 'My subject text';
  body = 0;


  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: myHTML, inlineImages:emailImages1});
```

I have also tried instead:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: myHTML, inlineImages:emailImages1,youtubeLogoBlob});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to include `youtubeLogoBlob` in `emailImages1` as the inlineImages.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please modify 3rd script in your question as follows.

#### From:

```
  emailImages1["chart"+i]= chartBlobs1[i] + youtubeLogoBlob;
}
myHTML = LogoStr + myHTML + myHTML2 + myHTML3 + myHTML4 + myHTML5 + chart1String + chart2String + chart3String + chart4String + myHTML6;
recipient = 'email@address';
subject = 'My subject text';
body = 0;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: myHTML, inlineImages:emailImages1});
```

#### To:

```
  emailImages1["chart"+i]= chartBlobs1[i]; // Modified
}
emailImages1["youtubeLogo"] = youtubeLogoBlob; // Added
myHTML = myHTML + myHTML2 + myHTML3 + myHTML4 + myHTML5 + chart1String + chart2String + chart3String + chart4String + myHTML6;
recipient = 'email@address';
subject = 'My subject text';
body = 0;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlBody: myHTML, inlineImages:emailImages1}); // Modified
```

#### Note:

- In your script, several variables which are not declared in the script you show, please be careful this.

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.